# WPF Editable ComboBox styling

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I have a small question: How do i style a WPF ComboBox with property IsEditable=True.
I used Blend to extract the default template.

Now i see a style ComboBoxEditableTextBox i've managed to set the borderbrush on default state but how can i set the border when i'm editing (focus on the textbox)?

Answer (score 1):

Did u try setting the `BorderThickness` upon (`IsFocused` = True and `IsReadOnly` = False) multi-triggers

Comment: The IsFocused on which template? Could you be more specific?